# Why is a SessionNotCreatedException breaking my Continuous Loop with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, exception

I have a Python script that uses Selenium to run a set of tests in a continuous loop. The script runs fine most of the time, but occasionally, it encounters a SessionNotCreatedException which causes the loop to break and stops the script from running further. I have tried to handle the exception in the code, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import SessionNotCreatedException
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from common_functions import send_logs
from forgot_password import EmailNotReceivedException
from datetime import datetime
import time
import traceback
import logging
import login
import forgot_password
import forgot_email
import access_chat
import contactus_noncustomer
import contactus_customer_chat


# List of tests to run in a loop and the corresponding test name
tests_to_run = [ 
    (login.runtest, "login"),
    (forgot_email.runtest, "forgot_email"), 
    (access_chat.runtest, "access_chat"),
    (contactus_noncustomer.runtest, "contactus_noncustomer"),
    (contactus_customer_chat.runtest, "contactus_customer_chat")
]

# Suppress the cert error msg when run from VM
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')

logging.basicConfig(filename='debugger.log', level=logging.INFO, format='%(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s - %(asctime)s')



while True:
    logging.info('-----------STARTING DEBUGGING-----------')
    for test, test_name in tests_to_run:
        try:
            # Location on the webdriver
            service = Service("C:\\Users\\cr\\Desktop\\chromedriver-win32\\chromedriver.exe")
            # The webdriver in use
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
            try:
                test(driver, wait)
            except EmailNotReceivedException as err:
                # Save a screen shot (windows - VM)
                driver.save_screenshot(f'C:\\Users\\cr\\Desktop\\selenium\\project\\debug_screenshots\\EE-{test_name}-{datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S")}.png')
                logging.info(f'An {type(err).__name__} was raised in {test_name}:\n{str(err)}')            
                
            except Exception as error:
                # Save a screen shot (windows - VM)
                driver.save_screenshot(f'C:\\Users\\cr\\Desktop\\selenium\\project\\debug_screenshots\\{test_name}-{datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y-%H-%M-%S")}.png')
                tb = traceback.format_exc()
                logging.info(f'An {type(error).__name__} was raised in {test_name}:\n{tb}')
            finally:
                driver.quit() 
        except SessionNotCreatedException as snce:
            # Save a screen shot (windows - VM)
            driver.save_screenshot(f'C:\\Users\\cr\\Desktop\\selenium\\project\\debug_screenshots\\SNC-{test_name}-{datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S")}.png')
            logging.info(f'A {type(snce).__name__} was raised during session creation in {test_name}:\n{str(snce)}')
        
    logging.info('-----------STOPPING DEBUGGING-----------')
    time.sleep(3600)
```

The script runs a series of tests using the Chrome WebDriver. I'm using Python's Selenium library with Chrome WebDriver on Windows.

The problem is that the SessionNotCreatedException doesn't seem to be caught by the exception handling block, as I can see from the console that the exception is raised, but the script doesn't continue the loop after handling it.  I want it to catch it, log the issue and move on.

I've also made sure to import the necessary exception class (SessionNotCreatedException) from selenium.common.exceptions.

Is there something I'm missing in my exception handling? How can I prevent this SessionNotCreatedException from breaking my continuous loop?

Any help or insights into this issue would be greatly appreciated. If you need more information or code snippets, please let me know, and I'll be happy to provide them.

Thank you in advance!